# Two asynch function calls filling the same array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

New to node and asynch programming.  Is there a problem with calling a function that fills an array in two different asynch calls.  A simple example of what I'm talking about is:

```
var myArray = [];

function filler(n) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            myArray.push(n + i);
        }
        resolve();
    });
}

filler(3).then(function () {
    console.log('Done with filler passing 3');
});

filler(10).then(function () {
    console.log('Done with filler passing 10');
});

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(myArray);
}, 3000);
```

Both asynch calls could be trying to push to myArray at the same exact time.  Is there a problem with that or does node.js handle that gracefully?  It works when I run it but I'm not sure if I'm just getting lucky that there's no collisions.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded. There will be no concurrency problems.

Comment: @Tomalak: JavaScript isn't single-threaded. NodeJS is, though.

Comment: Which engines are not?

Comment: @Tomalak: Just about all of them. You can have multiple threads even in browsers, with web workers. Those are, of course, nicely isolated from one another, communicating only via `postMessage`. For the kind of threads where they can stomp on each other's data, there's Rhino and Nashorn. The point is that *JavaScript*, the language, is silent on the topic of threads and does not require that there be only one. The *environment* dictates the threading model, within the confines of JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics.

Comment: Yes, but the standard lacks synchronization mechanisms or other features of languages with built-in parallelism (I guess Rhino has extensions for that), so except in the most pedantic way of putting it, Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, I have to disagree. It's not at all pedantic. JavaScript is not single-threaded in the same way that C is not single-threaded. It *does* lack synchronization semantics (because it's silent on the topic of threads), relying on the environment for them.

Comment: Well, pragmatically speaking... Any Javascript implementation that has any kind traction to speak of will run user code in a single thread (how many background threads are busy as webworkers or Ajax requests is completely irrelevant for the assessment). Yes, the spec does not enforce this particular behavior, I realize that. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder We are not actually a disagreement. You are focusing on the language as such, I get that, and you are right.

Answer (score 1):

> Both asynch calls could be trying to push to myArray at the same exact time.

The JavaScript concurrency model specifies a non-blocking event loop. There is only one executing event at a time and no event can run inbetween. Events occur in a predictable order. With this model JavaScript does not have the concurrency issues you might expect when you have threads.

For more reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Miscellaneous

Comment: *"JavaScript does not have the concurrency issues you might expect when you have threads."* That's true for NodeJS (which is single-threaded) and browsers (which isolate threads), but not true at the language level. The language says nothing about threads or concurrency. The environment can (and some do) have true multi-threading with the same concurrency issues you see in other languages.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you give an example of that?

Comment: See the comments on the question. My main point here is: *JavaScript*, the language, is silent on the topic of threads. Single- or multi-threading are features of the environment in which it's running, the *language* doesn't define anything in relation to threads at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you give an example of: _"The environment can .. have .. the same concurrency issues you see in other languages"_. You seem to imply this breaks assumptions about non-blocking and atomicity.

Comment: Rhino and Nashorn are the two active ones I can point to at present. At one time there was a multi-threaded NodeJS fork, and there have been various lesser attempts over the years. But again, that's not the point. The point is that JavaScript *the language* is silent on the topic of threading. JavaScript *the language* is no more single-threaded than C *the language* is single-threaded. In both cases, it's a matter of *environment*.

Comment: Re your edit: *"You seem to imply this breaks assumptions about non-blocking and atomicity."* Where do you see any atomicity or non-blocking guarantees in the specification? :-)

Comment: I have to get back to work. :-) But @OP, let's be clear: None of this relates to NodeJS. Halcyon's answer is quite correct that your two async callbacks cannot overlap on NodeJS, which is single-threaded for now and, I suspect, the foreseeable future. They also won't overlap in a browser environment (and I bet that will never change).